# Angular project not rerouting on refresh

Tags: angular, webserver, single-page-application

I am serving my Angular project built with CLI using the [`local-web-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-web-server) module.

The instructions state to use the command `--spa` followed by the name of your single page. This works fine on a refresh, except for pages where there are parameters being passed into the URL for example: `detail/1`. If I try and refresh this type of page my JavaScript and CSS files get a 404 error.

Comment: Any reason you can't use `ng serve`?

Comment: I'm trying to use the `dist` folder we get from `ng build` and host it so other people can look at the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed the issue was within my `index.html` file. I had changed the `base href` to `./` Changing it back to the original `/` fixed the issue.